# Concurrent deletion and field access

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is it legal for a second thread to delete an object while a first thread is still *potentially* inside a member function of that object, *if* the deletion occurs after the last (explicit) field access inside that function?

This will probably be clearer with an example:

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

struct handoff {
    std::atomic<int> flag{};

    void signal() { flag = 1; }
};

int main() {
    auto h = new handoff;

    auto t2 = std::thread([=]{
        while (!h->flag) {
        }
        delete h;
    });

    h->signal();

    t2.join();
}
```

Here, the `handoff h` object is used to communicate between T1 (the main thread) and T2. The flag field is initially zero, and T2 waits until it becomes non-zero then immediately deletes the `h` object. T1 calls `h->signal()` which sets the flag to non-zero. So the object will be deleted (by T2) while T1 is still potentially "inside" the `signal()` call. However, there are no further accesses to any fields of the `handoff` object in `signal()`.

Is it defined behavior? I think it is clear that calling a member function (even an empty one) is UB after an object has been deleted, but how about returning from one?

[TSAN thinks this is OK](https://godbolt.org/z/39ddqq) and I agree in practice this will work fine on sane architectures.

Comment: I don't see much difference from `void signal() { delete this; }` which I think is legal.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev Concerning `delete this`, I would be very carefully. [C++ FAQ: Is it legal (and moral) for a member function to say delete this?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this)

Answer (score 3):

Your code is safe. There is no such concept of being "inside" an object. You either access (as in: read write) the object or not. Method or not, its just a function. However in your concrete case accessing `this` after `flag = 1` line in `signal` method is not safe. So it is a matter of concrete code, not of being inside or not.

Also you are correct that calling a member function after delete is UB. But that's not the case. The "call" event already happened before delete, that is not UB.